# What is the meaning of the 'AnalyzeTemporaryDtors' option in clang-tidy?

Tags: clang-tidy

The `clang-tidy --dump-config` command produces something like this:

```
---
Checks:          'clang-diagnostic-*,clang-analyzer-*'
WarningsAsErrors: ''
HeaderFilterRegex: ''
AnalyzeTemporaryDtors: false
FormatStyle:     none
User:            [...]
CheckOptions:
  - key:             [...]
    value:           [...]
[...]
```

What is the meaning of the `AnalyzeTemporaryDtors` option? What does it change when it is set to `true`? All the other options are documented, but I could not find any documentation related to this one, and I could not find any difference changing the value of the option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`AnalyzeTemporaryDtors` is an artifact from an older `clang-tidy` version, notably 6 and below.

The corresponding option `-analyze-temporary-dtors=` was removed, but since a lot of people do `-dump-config` (which dumps every option), removing `AnalyzeTemporaryDtors` apparently broke a lot of projects with such generated `.clang-tidy`, so it was added back  for compatibility purposes: https://reviews.llvm.org/rG6e76a1b1ff98b27b82689b6294cde1d355be088f.

Feel free to remove it from your `.clang-tidy`.